# Images missing when printing in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9

Platform: ASP.NET 2.0 (C#) + IIS 7

Hi all,

I have a web form that generates a selection of images (barcodes). The page is displayed as expected in IE9. However, when printed the images are replaced by the classic red X.

This only happens on *some* clients with IE9, but not all. I've tried resetting the clients, matching settings with a working client and so on, but nothing seems to change.

Any help / tips will be greatly appreciated as my googling had lead me nowhere :(

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It could be a case of needing a seperate css for print, so it removes anything unneccassary from the page before printing, so there is no conflict between roots and directories.

Just a thought.